# Is it possible to use a same onClick for both AlertDialog and View?

Tags: java, android, onclick

My activity has an accept button witch sends intent to parent through onClickOkayButton method. I have overriden the onBackPressed() method so that it shows an AlertDialog asking the user if he really wishes to leave or if he wants to save the preferences, witch does the exact same action as the accept button.

Is it possible to merge both onClick methods into one so I don't need to copy/paste in case of editing one of those, even if both methods use different parameters?

```
public void onClickOkayButton(View view) {

// THIS IS THE ACCEPT BUTTON
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.surveyadd_name_edittext);
    String title = editText.getText().toString();
    if (!(title.matches("")) || !(title.isEmpty()) || !(title.equals("")) ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.surveyadd_warn_notitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (adapter.getCount() != 0) {
        showAlertDialog();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public void showAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.surveyadd_warn_back_message);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.surveyadd_warn_back_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

// THIS WAS COPIED FROM THE ACCEPT BUTTON
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.surveyadd_name_edittext);
            String title = editText.getText().toString();
            if (!(title.matches("")) || !(title.isEmpty()) || !(title.equals("")) ) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.surveyadd_warn_notitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
// UP TO HERE

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.surveyadd_warn_back_erase, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use the same callback methods because they are from different interfaces.

What you should do is move all the common code into a third method and just call it from both click handlers like below:

```
private void setResultAndFinish() {
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.surveyadd_name_edittext);
    String title = editText.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.surveyadd_warn_notitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And then the handlers:

```
public void onClickOkayButton(View view) {
    setResultAndFinish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    setResultAndFinish();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for =)

Comment: No problem. Also note I replaced the first if statement with `!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)` which hopefully simplifies the check you were doing before.